# how to delete and objects from the db without refreshing the page?

Tags: python, django, ajax, rest

I have a page that shows every objects in the database, this is handled by an ajax function that gets a JSON file containing every objects in the db and renders out some html code for every object.
There's also a classic Django ModelForm that allows the creations of new db's objects, the new objects is instantly loaded with the others.

I want an html button for every objects that deletes it "on the fly", so without redirecting to a Detail Delete template.

```
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type:'DELETE'
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyApp/list-api/' + $(this).attr('data-id')
}
```

When the button is clicked it should send a DELETE request to the url of the detail api of the object. Nothing happens, no new request in the network tab of the browser.

This is my index.html

```html
<body>
    <h2>coffee orders</h2>
    <ul id="orders">

    </ul>

    <h4>Add coffee order</h4>

<form method="POST" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button id="add-order" type="submit">Add!!!</button>
</form>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'MyApp/jquery_js.js' %}"></script>

</body>
```

This is my jquery.js,
this function get the api and renders out the infos about the object and a delete button which doens't work.

```
$(function (){

    var $orders = $('#orders')

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyApp/list-api/?format=json',
        success: function(orders) {
            $.each(orders, function(i, order){
                $orders.append('<li>name: '+order.name+', drink: 
                               '+order.drink+'</li>')
                $orders.append("<form method='DELETE'><button data-id=" + 
                               (order.pk)+" class='remove'>X</button>")
            });
        },
        error: function() {
        alert('errore caricamento ordini');
        }
    });
```

```py
def list_create_view(request):
    form = DrinkModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = request.user
        form.save()
        form = DrinkModelForm()
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "MyApp/index.html", context)


class OrderListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    pass
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.all()


class OrderDetailView(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    pass
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        return get_object_or_404(Order, pk=id_)
```

The X button should delete the objects from the db but nothings happens, I'm new to jquery so any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `OrderDetailView` for deletion and remove that `pass` from the class definition. BTW, you don't need to override the `get_object` method if you're passing the `pk` on the URL.

**views.py**

```py
class OrderDetailView(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks for making my view cleaner, yes I could use the django rest framework panel for deletion or the django admin panel but the point is that I want to handle deletion from the same html template that handles retrieving and creation. Basically I want to give the user the power to delete obj from the db